# Hook Into the_content Filter For JSON API Only

Tags: filters, json, plugin-json-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to remove the shortcodes from my JSON output which I'm using the [Wordpress JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) for.

I need to remove the shortcodes from the content before `do_shortcode` is applied which will cause the shortcodes to render. The reason being that they will break in my mobile app (they reference various js etc.. not in the app)

I've found a [Strip Shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes) function which I can hook into `the_content` filter as these filters are applied by the plugin before it encodes it to JSON. But how can I only do this when I am working with a request for json information as I don't want to remove the shortcodes on the general site.

I know I can check for things like `is_single()` or `is_home()` but I can't see anything similar which would tell me if it's for a JSON output.

Is there anyway I can tell if it is or not so I can choose when to use the strip shortcodes function?

One thing I thought about was examining the url to see if `json` is in it, but I was hoping there could be something more robust?

Comment: It looks like this plugin includes some hooks/filters: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#5.1.-Plugin-hooks

Comment: Yes I saw them but I don't think they will help me do what I want unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not as much filtering content, as content assuming too much about context and doing things that *content* shouldn't really. You don't read the book where text decides to color itself, it's decided for it.

I would suggest to consider decoupling content from active context-specific functionality. You can still use shortcodes, but instead of them actively spitting out JavaScript to a page there should be more flexible and do things like setting some "flags" for JS to be output in footer and so on.

Comment: While I agree, Unfortunately things like this aren't always in my control. I use third party plugins to allow the editors to make graphs/polls and other things, the sacrifice with that is I don't have complete control, and if the plugin needs to output it's script in the content to make a chart work, it just does it unfortunately, so that's why I am trying to go this route and take out the shortcodes altogether

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out in the end by modifying one of the core files of the plugin

If you look in json-api/models/post.php there's a function set_content_value() which shows where the plugin is pulling in the content. Here you can modify it as needed, in my case I used it to remove certain shortcodes with the Wordpress remove_shortcode() function